# Add 2nd sub nav to accordion style menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation, accordion

I'm looking to have an additional subnav to this accordion menu. I tried to add a child element to the nav ul li, but that didn't seem to work. Ideally, I would like to be able to list web projects under "web" and print under "print".

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/schermerb/rGMAu/1/

```
.header button {
    cursor:pointer;
    float:right;
    padding:5px;
    margin:10px 10px;
    border:none;
    border:1px solid #ececec;
    background:#444;
    color:#ececec;
}
.nav {
    text-align:center;
    background:#444;
}
.nav ul li {
    text-transform:capitalize;
    display:block;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ececec;
}
.nav a {
    display:block;
    padding:10px;
    color:#ececec;
}
.nav a:hover {
    background:#029b9d;
    color:#ececec;
}

<button id="show">Menu <span>+</span>  <span style="display:none;">-</span>
</button>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Web</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Print</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your js

```
$('.nav, .nav li ul').hide();
$('#show').click(function () {
    $(".nav").toggle();
    $("span").toggle();
});
$('.nav li').click(function(){
    $(this).children('ul').toggle();
});
```

**[Updated jsFiddle File](http://jsfiddle.net/rGMAu/4/)**

Comment: Works perfect, thank you. I'll accept this once the time limit is up.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a child element was the right path.

http://jsfiddle.net/jonigiuro/rGMAu/2/

```
<li><a href="#">Web</a>
    <ul class="sub">
        <li class="item">item1</li>
        <li class="item">item2</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

You hide the child element by default, and when you hover on the parent, you show the it:

```
ul li:hover ul
```

Here's the revelant css for your case:

```
.nav ul li ul {
    color: red;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: none;
}

.nav ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}

.nav ul li ul li {
    padding: 10px 0;
}
```

Comment: Works great, but is there a way to have onclick and not on:hover?